# Reference class from dll in cpp

Tags: c++, class, dll, reference, include

Im new to cpp, and have a question. How do i reference a class inside a dll?

```
#include <Interceptor.dll>
```

This is how im including the file.

Im using Interceptor.dll, and wish to use Input class from inside it.

Comment: You include headers. You don't include a dll.

Comment: is this really standard `c++` and not managed `c++` /CLR?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use objects from a library, you should include the headers for that library. These headers tell your compiler which objects (and functions) are available in the library.

Comment: how to get the lib header?

Comment: That depends on the library... You can't restore it from the `.dll` alone, but the authors of the `.dll` probably provide it somewhere.

Comment: Can't i generate it from lib's project solution? There is no .h file in it.

Comment: You probably also need or at least want an import library if we are talking about standard `c++` and not CLR.